# C++ KafkaConsumer & Queue

Tags: c++, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I rewrite my C++ code to use **KafkaConsumer** and **Queue**.
This is a snippet (in pseudo code) from my source code:

```
conf = RdKafka::Conf::create(RdKafka::Conf::CONF_GLOBAL);
//set basic conf
setGlobalConf("bootstrap.servers", brokers);
setGlobalConf("metadata.broker.list", brokers);
setGlobalConf("client.id", "app-meteo");
setGlobalConf("compression.codec", "snappy");
//set group id
setGlobalConf("group.id", params.at("group.id"));

//set default_topic_conf
tconf = RdKafka::Conf::create(RdKafka::Conf::CONF_TOPIC);
setConf(tconf, "auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
conf->set("default_topic_conf", tconf, errstr);

//create consuner
auto consumer = RdKafka::KafkaConsumer::create(conf, errstr);
consumer->subscribe("my_topic");

//create the queue for that consumer
auto queue = RdKafka::Queue::create(consumer);

//then ...
while (true)
{
    RdKafka::Message* msg = consumer->consume(1000);
    do_smthg(*msg, nullptr);
}
```

the problem here is that msg contains an error that it's always: **RdKafka::ERR__TIMED_OUT**

I don't know why this happens even if there are a lot of message inside **my_topic**.

Note: I followed the FAQ and the documentation, but probably I miss something.

Comment: you can find the source code here: https://github.com/meox/KClient